# New lines are not included to String count in iOS Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a weird problem in iOS 14.1/Swift 5 that caused many griefs and consumed hours, until I understood what's going on. I still want to know if this is a bug or "by design". In the latter case, please provide a link describing the behavior and provide a list of other characters that are not counted.

Let us assume that I have a string like below:

```
let data = "l1\r\nl2\r\nl3"
```

I need to create an HTTP response manually and replace the Content-Length with the data length. I use a template for that:

```
static let RESPONSE = 
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: LENGTH
Content-Type: text/plain

DATA
""".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
```

Finally, I create a response from a template:

```
let response = RESPONSE.replacingOccurrences(of: ": LENGTH", with: ": \(data.count)")
        .replacingOccurrences(of:"DATA", with:data)
```

As a result, Content-Length was set to 8, not to 10, and a client didn't receive "l3".

Please note that the string with carriage returns has been generated by Apple's own BASE64 API, so there is nothing "special" that I did here myself:

```
Data(digest).base64EncodedString(options: [.lineLength64Characters])
```

Very strange behavior that I didn't see in any other languages.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It returns 19 as expected. I'm not sure why you're expecting 20. The `"""` syntax does not insert a newline at the beginning or end. Your `data` is `"line1\n\nline2\n\nline3"`

Comment: Note that `"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n".count` is 8.

Comment: Right, 19, since last "\n " is not added. I'll change, but still it should be 19, while in my case it returns 18. This is just an example. In real program I'm missing dozens of uncounted newlines. What version of SwiftUI and iOS are you on? it's 5 and 14.1 in my case

Comment: This has nothing to do with SwiftUI. I don't know what you mean by "SwiftUI 5." The current version of SwiftUI is 2 (if SwiftUI even has independent versions).

Comment: I am 100% certain this is not iOS-version specific. Your string is not what you think it is. Simplify your problem to static strings that you know precisely what they contain and I'm certain this will work. Then dig into your program to see where your string is not the same.

Comment: See screenshot in OP in regard of Swift version. Not sure what you mean by static strings. Response is created dynamically.

Comment: "Swift Language Version" is not related to SwiftUI. SwiftUI is a framework released last year. It's not part of "Swift" even though it included it in the name, much like CryptoSwift is not part of Swift. They're both just written in Swift.

Comment: By "static strings" I mean "just put the strings in code like you've done in your example, where everything works exactly as expected." And yes, I'm testing with Swift 5. Your issue is that your dynamic string is not exactly what you think it is. You need to explore why it's not what you think it is. Swift is not broken here; you just have a string creation bug in your code.

Comment: Changed Swift UI to Swift to make it more clear, but it's not essential here. I think, I found the problem. In the generated text it was actually \r\n sequence, not \n\n, but the qs stays: are carriage returns are not supposed to be counted? They are generated by Apple's own base64 API, BTW. I'll update the qs

Comment: Updated OP and this is very easy to reproduce now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift string indexing combines "\r\n" as one char instead of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940147/swift-string-indexing-combines-r-n-as-one-char-instead-of-two)

Comment: Paul has provided the best answer that matches my qs. I've accepted. What still puzzles me is that judging from the quoted doc, \r alone and \r\n are both considered as a "new line" character and consequently are counted as one. It's mind blowing.

Answer (score 2):

Swift treats the combination of `\r\n` as a single newline character (abbreviated in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127014-isnewline) to CR-LF).

```
let combo = Character('\r\n')
print(combo.isNewline) // true
```

So when you convert this `Character` to a `String` and count it you get the answer one.

```
print(String(combo).count) // 1
```

`Character` has no `count` because by definition it represents a single *user-perceived* character even if it is constructed from a number of components.

I guess Swift's developers decided that the count property of `String` should output the number of *user perceived* characters, and since `\r\n` to all intents and purposes has the same effect has a single newline character it is counted as a single character.

Note however that `String` does not throw away the data from which it was constructed; you can still get the 'raw' count property that is most relevant to your case via the `unicodeScalars` property.

```
let data = "l1\r\nl2\r\nl3"
print(data.count) // 8
print(data.unicodeScalars.count)  // 10
```

By the way, it's not just CR-LF that gets this special treatment; national flag emojis are a single user perceived character that are actually composed of two scalars.

```
let unionJack = Character("")
        
for scalar in unionJack.unicodeScalars {
   print(String(scalar.value, radix: 16).uppercased()  )
}

// 1F1EC
// 1F1E7
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Good ref. Judging from the doc you quoted, \r alone and \r\n are both represent a single newline character that will be counted as 1. Something is deeply wrong with brains of the people who have decided to do it this way :)

Comment: I think you're being a little harsh there Oleg! I expect a fair bit of thought goes into decisions like that. Anyway, at least you've got an explanation now.

Comment: Let us not go to the discussion about "fair bit of thought" since it could be easily a rat hole. There are common ways of doing *simple* things though and a common understanding of those ways. Deviating from them should be really motivated well, which I don't think the case here.

Comment: @PaulPatterson your answer was a lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change `data.count` to `data.utf16.count` in order to get the "outside world" view of how "long" the string is.

(Alternatively you could say `(data as NSString).length`.)